# How to find line number containing a string and replace the whole line with another string?

Tags: vb.net

For ex.

If i have a line in a txt document "text.txt".Now what i want to do is open the file and read the contents.

When it find this "search.selectedEngine" term then it should delete that particular line and replace it with another string ("REPLACED STRING").

And then save the text document.

It would be great if you could give me the source for this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/.*search\.selectedEngine.*/REPLACED STRING/g' /PATH/TO/FILE >/PATH/TO/NEW/FILE
```

This is case sensitive.

Comment: This would be a good answer but the tag is VB.NET. I don't think a Unix utility will work here

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer to a question tagged VB.NET? Am I missing something? Or is your question mistagged?